# Check Box Issue in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I am trying to display only the desired country came under the particular flag. But when I change the Radio Button and change the selection of Check Box it does not work and after first selection it is displaying all the countries names..

```
//Code for Option Buttons

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PKFlag.CheckedChanged
          PakFlag.Visible = PKFlag.Checked
    End Sub

//Code for Check Boxes

    Private Sub CH_KW_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CH_KW.CheckedChanged
        If KuwaitFlag.Checked = True And CH_KW.Checked = True Then
            LBL_KW.Visible = True
        Else
            LBL_KW.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Well, first thing. Try to give to your controls meaningful names.

Comment: @Steve How can i give meaningful name to Controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a sub like this:

```
Private Sub AdjustVisibleName()
  LBL_KW.Visible = (KuwaitFlag.Checked = True AndAlso CH_KW.Checked = True)
  'Exactly the same for the other countries
End Sub
```

Then in the CheckedChanged event handler for every checkbox and radiobutton you call this function.
That way you can make sure that the displayed name is always up to date.